# what is wrong with my servlet - getting java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am new to java servlets and trying to open my login page. Here is the service method of the servlet:

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Here is my login.jsp file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>


<form action="servletexample" method="post">
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>User Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="firstname" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="lastname" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

When i run the project, i get the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Cannot forward after response has been committed

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message Cannot forward after response has been committed

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
com.exaple.tutorial.ServletExample.service(ServletExample.java:33)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.37 logs.
```

And here is the screenshot of WebContent Folder:

[image]

And finally the web.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>ServletsJSPExample</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>ServletExample</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ServletExample</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>com.exaple.tutorial.ServletExample</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletExample</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servletexample</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why are you initializing the PrintWriter in your service method. This may be the reason of getting 500 internal error because as soon as you exit your service method, writer will be flushed/closed. And when you try to render the jsp after forwarding the request it will throw response already committed server 500 error. So comment out your printwriter instance and then try to forward the request to login.jsp.

This form the [javadocs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) :

> forward should be called before the response has been committed to the
>   client (before response body output has been flushed). If the response
>   already has been committed, this method throws an
>   IllegalStateException. **Uncommitted output in the response buffer is
>   automatically cleared before the forward.**

**Another important thing** :

You aren't returning after the forward() method as that method does not magically terminates the code execution and jumps out of the method . You have to return from the method and stop the execution of the remnant of the code yourself.

Comment: Other jsp page called index.jsp works fine in my project. I tried what you said but still getting same error. I edited question and put the web.xml file can you have a look at it can there be a problem in xml file?

Comment: @bigO Updated the answer, you need to add a return after your forward method call.